# Unicode to text

Tags: java, unicode

so I have problem parsing page content.

Here is method with content page parse.

```
public static void URLParse() throws IOException, ParseException {
        URL url = new URL("http://kpiparse.esy.es/api/getGroupSchedule?apikey=secretkey123&group=%D1%96%D0%BE-23");

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("text/html;\\s+charset=([^\\s]+)\\s*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(con.getContentType());

        /* If Content-Type doesn't match this pre-conception, choose default and 
         * hope for the best. */
        String charset = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "cp1251";
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset);
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
          int ch = r.read();
          if (ch < 0)
            break;
          buf.append((char) ch);
        }
        String str = buf.toString();
        System.out.println(str);    
        }
```

I get output like this:

```
{"schedule":{"week1":{"monday":{"classes":{"1":"","2":"\u0406\u043d\u043e\u0437\u0435\u043c\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u043e\u0432\u0430 \u0437\u04`
```

and many unicode after.

Is there any way to show output as:

```
{"schedule":{"week1":{"monday":{"classes":{"1":"","2":"Іноземна мова загальнотехнічного спрямування вик. Лубянова О. В.227-18 Прак","3":"Системне програмування-1 ст.вик. Порєв В. М.307-18 Лек","4":"Комп'ютерна електроніка ст.вик. Виноградов Ю. М.514-18 Лаб","5":""`?
```

Comment: is the charset that you handle from the website is it the correct charset that you have to use ?

Comment: @Mifmif I try to use UTF8, got the same

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try UTF-8?  That is, including the dash?  Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: @demongolem `String charset = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "UTF-8";` like this?

Comment: @user3735097 Yes.  Sometimes both ways are accepted in Java, but UTF-8 is the preferred (and guaranteed) way of writing it.  The link I gave you says "Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard charsets..." and lists UTF-8.

Comment: @demongolem Got the same..

Comment: Isn't it simply that the server literally sends `\u0406`, etc? What do you get with something like curl? In that case character encoding has nothing to do with it (as long as its a superset of ASCII). Hopefully your JSON parser (which I assume is the next step) can turn them into ‘proper’ characters.

Comment: @Biffen I cant provide you my parser)

Comment: @silvananight17 I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Biffen I mean I can give you my parser code, I dont kmow how to parse it correctly withouy /u****

Comment: @silvananight17 I'm not particularly interested in the parser. In case my first comment wasn't clear, I'll try to rephrase it: It looks to me like the server is *literally* sending `\u0406`, as in backslash followed by the letter U and so on. If that's the case, then changing *character encoding* will *not* make a difference. To ascertain whether my theory is right, you could use some other tool (e.g. curl) to make the HTTP request and inspect the *raw* data. This would also let you have a look at the content type of the response, although, once again, I don't think it is of any importance.

Comment: @silvananight17 (cont'd) The reason I mentioned ‘parser’ is that *some* JSON parsers will convert the `\u...` constructs for you, so that by the time you use the data, you'll have what you want.